# Split a string by '_'

Tags: python-3.x

I have a number of files in a directory with the following file format:

```
roll_#_oe_yyyy-mm-dd.csv
```

where `#` is a integer and `yyyy-mm-dd` is a date (for example roll_6_oe_2008-02-12).

I am trying to use the split function so I can return the number on its own. So for example:

roll_6_oe_2008-02-12 would yield 6
and
roll_14_oe_2008-02-12 would yield 14

I have tried :

```
filename.split("_")
```

but cannot write the number to a variable. What can I try next?

Comment: Did you try indexing the list?

Comment: `number = int(filename.split("_")[1])` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that: `filename = 'roll_14_oe_2008-02-12'`

`print(filename.split('_'))`  evaluates to `['roll', '14', 'oe', '2008-02-12']`

The number you want to retrieve is in the 2nd position of the list:

```
my_number = filename.split('_')[1]
```

---

You could also extract the number using regex:

```
import re

filename = 'roll_134_oe_2008-02-12'

number_match = re.match("roll_*(\d+)", filename)
if number_match:
    print number_match.group(1)
```

Working example for both methods: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_jEFOv5N5GN_2.py